# Setting an Excel Template as a Library template

Tags: sharepoint-server

How do I set my own Excel temlplate as the default template for a SharePoint Library? How do I save the template to the Forms folder in my Document Library?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use Excel files as forms - something like Excel survey for Office 365?

About content type: 
Office 365 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaks/archive/2011/05/19/deploying-a-document-template-file-in-content-type-in-a-office365-sandboxed-solution.aspx